# How to do raw join with OrmLite

Tags: android, ormlite

Due to OrmLite's nature, We can't join two table which without any relationship. (Actually they have, but not specify in class).
So how to run raw join query, and retrieve raw cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AndroidDatabaseResults result = (AndroidDatabaseResults) yourDao
                .queryRaw("your query statement", arg1, arg2).closeableIterator()
                .getRawResults();

Cursor cursor = result.getRawCursor();
```